# Best Microcontroller for .net?

Tags: .net, microcontroller

What is the Best Microcontroller for .net ?

(best = popular, good value, has many I/0, able to get support)

Comment: what do you want to do with it besides I/O?

Comment: Nothing much really, only need I/0
Netdriuno looks good but not sure if it's popular? I'm still using the c version! Nothing is wrong with it! Just thought I'll try a new toy ;)

Comment: Think I'll just settle for the NETdruino looks like fun :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The porting kit for the .NET Micro Framework directly supports AT91, BF537, Cortex-M3, LPC22XX, LPC24XX, MC9328, PXA271 and SH2.  Get the data-sheets from their manufacturers to see what you like.